# Laravel Eloquent - Having trouble querying relationship with ownership

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get all categories and within those categories, only items that belong to the logged in user. If there are none, the category should still be there.

This is what I tried. Still getting items from other users.

```
$categories = Category::parents()
                        ->with(['lineItems' => function ($query) use($id) {
                                $query->where('user_id', $id);
                            }])->get();
```

Haven't been able to find anything that works. (using laravel 5.7)

**Relationships**

Category

```
public function lineItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LineItem::class);
}
```

LineItems

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @Varun.Kumar I get all of the categories and all lineItems, regardless of user.

Comment: Can you include your `lineItems()` relationship?

Comment: @TravisBritz added!

Comment: @Shevy how are you accessing $categories? It's not `$categories->lineItems()` (which would re-run the query), is it? (note the parenthesis)

Comment: I loop through in blade. At line item level:
`@foreach ($child->lineItems as $line)
{{ $line->description}}
@endforeach`

Comment: Hi @Shevy! Can you please add `\DB::enableQueryLog();` above your query. And then add `dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` after your query. Then show us screenshot of it? So we will see your `SQL` and see what is wrong.

Comment: @MakashovNurbol I found a solution but not sure it's best. It's below. Your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Travis's question made me think about my loop. My `with` was affecting my top level categories which left its children's line items without the `where` user. There's probably a more elegant method of doing this but this is what ended up working.

This queries the child's line items and the grandchild's line items.

```
$categories = Category::parents()->ordered()
                    ->with(['children.lineItems' => function($q) use($id) {
                        $q->where('user_id', '=', $id);
                    }, 'children.children.lineItems' => function($q) use($id) {
                        $q->where('user_id', '=', $id);
                    }])->get();
```

Comment: Aha, so there were more relationships being lazily loaded without constraints. What you have here should be fine as long as you're not planning to load more levels of child categories. If you end up 6 levels deep, then it might be time to refactor.

Comment: In my question version I had them in the with to but realized I didn’t actually need it. That’s makes it eager, right? @travis-britz

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the `::parents()` method is coming from (I can't find documentation for it anywhere; is it something you wrote?), but it seems like

```
$categories = Category::all()
                      ->with(['lineItems' => function ($query) use ($id) {
                          $query->where('user_id', $id);
                     }])->get();
```

might work?

Comment: You can't chain on all(). get() takes its place when you query. The parents() is a scope. It gets categories with no parent id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$categories = Category::parents()
                        ->whereHas('lineItems', function ($query) use($id) {
                                $query->where('user_id', $id);
                        })->get();
```

Comment: This only gets parent categories that have lineItems. No parent categories have lineItems so it returns nothing.

Comment: Is your structure has only 2 levels of category? Or it can have more than 2 levels like Vehicles -> Cars -> BMW -> 3.20d

Comment: it currently just has 3 levels. I would like it to have more and be more flexible.

Comment: I got it, it's more complicated than i thought. But what i can offer is an alternative such that, you should fetch a LineItem collection with their Category relation. This is easier and looks more formal, imo though. And maybe you can group by with their categories. To sum up, starting to the query with LineItem:: looks like a better practise.